# C# startIndex + length > this.length

Tags: c#

I`m experimenting a weird issue. I code a huge amount of data ( an struct )  into an hex string and upload to the server as varbin. Then I download it and, sometimes it cant be decoded. So I decided to code some prints:

```
public static void d(String TAG, String message)
{
    int maxLogSize = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i <= message.Length / maxLogSize; i++)
    {
        int start = i * maxLogSize;
        int end = (i + 1) * maxLogSize;
        if (end > message.Length - 1)
            end = message.Length - 1;
        //end = end > message.Count() ? message.Count() : end;
        print(message.Substring(start, end));
        print("start: " + start.ToString() + " end: " + end.ToString() + " size: " + message.Length);
    }
}
```

then in the try/catch of the server response coroutine I get this:

```
11-03 15:03:02.616 13103-13117/com.Mindfunk.minus I/Unity: start: 63000 end: 64000 size: 127834

(Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)
11-03 15:03:02.636 13103-13117/com.Mindfunk.minus I/Unity: There was an error decoding this challenge replay . Maybe it is corrupted.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex + length > this.length
Parameter name: length
    at System.String.Substring (Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at DBConnection+Log.d (System.String TAG, System.String message) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at DBConnection+<DownloadChallengeReplay>c__IteratorE.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I don't know why it can't read after half of the string, only thought about the size, because with not so big sets of data it works like a charm.

log2(64000) is approximately 16. I'm assuming max length for a C# string is 16 bits but surprise! I found it is 32 bits. Thinking about `string.substring` and `string.length` as not at all correlated methods, but why?

Comment: If it's ten bytes long, and you start at byte five, and then you add ten to five, you're adding startIndex (5) to Length (10) and getting 15. 15 > 10. If that's what the code is actually doing.

Comment: Thanks! I copied the function from android Java assuming the methods are the same....

Comment: Ahh! Yeah, little details like that will always differ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> start: 63000 end: 64000

```
 message.Substring(start, end)
```

The second argument to Substring is the *length* of the string to extract.  You are telling it to start at position 63000 and retrieve the next 64000 characters.